# Turn a text into an array of strings, find the string that is sent in the second position, and replace it with the string in the third position

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I am completely stuck on where to go regarding this problem. What I am trying to do is take a word from a string of words, and replace it with a word from another string.
For example, one of the examples I was prompted with was:

```
//changeWords("Hi nice to meet you", "hi", "hello") returns ["hello", "nice", "to", "meet", "you"]
```

Here is what I have typed out so far:

```
public static String[] changeWords(String text, String find, String replace)
  {
     String[] words = new String[0];
     words = text.split(" ");
     if (words[0] == find) {
       words[0].set(replace);
     }
    return words;
  }
```

Admittedly, my code is not too detailed or far into finding a solution, but I would like some guidance on where to proceed from what I have. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of checking the word at the 0th position, loop though the string array and compare each word. Once a match is found, replace the word using words[i] = replace and break out of the loop.

Comment: You MUST compare objects in java using `.equals()`, not `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @D George has said, you need to loop through with a loop and use the .equals() method to compare strings. You can modify your code to look like this...
or use the .replaceFirst() method of the string object to replace the first occurrence of the search string. Try this

```
public static String[] changeWords(String text, String find, String replace)
  {
     String[] words = new String[0];
     words = text.split(" ");
     for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
       if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(find)) {
         words[i]=replace;
         break;
       }
     }
    return words;
  }
```

OR THIS

```
public static String[] changeWords(String text, String find, String replace)
{
   return text.replaceFirst(find, replace);
}
```

The approach above is well suited in a situation where you want to replace only the first occurrence of the search string. if you want to replace all the occurences of the search string, you do not need to use an array as the string object comes with a replace method. you can do this to replace all occurrences:

```
public static String[] changeWords(String text, String find, String replace)
  {
    return text.replace(find, replace);
  }
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but now my program is only replacing the first instance of each word, and like Arvind Kumar Avinash pointed out, does not account for case-insensitive examples. The example I posted is currently returning "Hi nice to meet you". An aide I am consulting with has told me that the size of the array words is part of the problem.

Comment: you can use the .equalsIgnoreCase() method to find a match in a non-case sensitive way

Comment: Thanks a lot. I consulted a bit with another student to help finish the code, but what you offered helped a lot in solving it!